# How to handle ngx-translate get in angular service?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a problem with getting access to undefind config fields from TooltipConfig which is map in angular services. Fields are assign from ngx-transalate service using ngx-translate get method. When i was trying to assing this map fields using synchronous instant method sometimes content wasn't ready and displaying keys from json file. Can someone help me with this problem?

```
@Injectable()
export class TooltipConfig {
  textTooltip: string;
  textLink: string;
  public config = new Map<string, TooltipModel>([
    [
      'uniqueId',
      {
        textTooltip: this.textTooltip,
        textLink: this.textLink
      }
    ]
  ]);

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService
      .get(
        'common.textTooltip', 
        'common.textLink')
      .subscribe((resource: Object) => {
        this.textTooltip = resource['common.textTooltip'],
        this.textLink = resource['common.textLink'];
      });
  }
}
```